# New to WPF, how would I create these colored bars in my form?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, background-color

[image]

I'm trying to ditch Windows Forms, and learn to use WPF professionally from now on. Pictured above is a form done in Windows Forms that I'd like to recreate in WPF.

Here is the XAML I have so far:

```
<Window x:Class="PizzaSoftware.UI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="297" Width="466" >
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".20*"/>    
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>     
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0">
            <Backcolor?
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Is this even the right approach, I mean using a Rectangle. In my Windows Forms example, I used a Panel and gave it a .BackColor property.

What's the WPF way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: You could also make the entire background orange and the background of the center column content white.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your approach is just fine. Set the background color with the `Fill` property:

```
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="Orange" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Fill="Orange" />
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="0" 
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Fill="Orange" />
```

Comment: The alignments are unnecessary, because this is the default.

Comment: Excellent point, +1.  For someone new to WPF, this is a very important thing to note, so I will leave it.

Answer (score 3):

Set the background of the window to your orange color. Then set the background of the grid to white, set the width of the grid so that it leaves space on either side, and set the grids HorizontalAlignment to center.

```
<Windows ....
    Background="Orange>
  <Grid Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300">
  ...
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Adding Rectangles into the grid actually add more elements into the visual tree. While this example is not complex in the first place, I always advocate using less elements in the visual tree.

Answer (score 0):

I'd skip the rectangle and set the background color on the grid itself, then set colors on components within to grid.

```
<Grid Background="Orange">
```

Comment: Or you could go with @Joel Lucsy and set it on the window, which might even suit you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Background` property of your grid to Orange and then add your control in the middle column and Set its `Background` property to White. Here is a sample code:

```
<Window x:Class="PizzaSoftware.UI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="297" Width="466" 
        Height="297"
        Width="466">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True" Background="Orange">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".20*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".20*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--Control with white background in second column-->
        <GroupBox Background="White" Grid.Column="1">
            <!-- Groupbox content here-->
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```